# Can't install net.liftweb:lift-json_2.13 in Databricks

Tags: lift, azure-databricks, lift-json

I am trying to install net.liftweb:lift-json_2.13:3.4.1 into a Databricks cluster (Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

However I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: unresolved dependency: net.liftweb:lift:1.2.1: not found
```

When I try to install the net.liftweb:lift:1.2.1 I am getting the following error:

```
Maven Dependencies not found: unresolved dependency: net.liftweb:lift:1.2.1: not found Please try again by excluding these dependencies.
```

I also had no success with other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make third-party or locally-built code available to notebooks and jobs running on your clusters, you can install a library. Libraries can be written in Python, Java, Scala, and R. You can upload Java, Scala, and Python libraries and point to external packages in PyPI, Maven, and CRAN repositories.

**Steps to install third party libraries:**

**Step1:** Create Databricks Cluster.

**Step2:** Select the cluster created.

**Step3:** Select Libraries => Install New => Select Library Source = "Maven" => Coordinates => Search Packages => Select Maven Central => Search for the package required. Example: (lift json) => Select the version ( net.liftweb » lift-json_2.13 » 3.4.1) required => Install

[image]

Successfully installed ( net.liftweb » lift-json_2.13 » 3.4.1) library.

[image]

For more details, refer "[Azure Databricks - libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is exactly what I did, however in my case I got the errors mentioned =[

Comment: Well, I was very unhappy with this because you used the same type of cluster than me and it worked. So I decided to create a new cluster and try again, then it finally 
 worked. Who knows what happened . . .

Comment: I have used same cluster as yours Databricks cluster (Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11).